# Apply a function over list of Dataframes using optim()

Tags: r, function, lapply

I am trying to figure out a way to run a list of many dataframes through an optimization function. I currently have to go dataframe by dataframe to get it to work properly, as seen below by given code. Any help how to automate this process with lapply or for loop? Thanks.

```
# required library
library(dplyr)

A <- "Cheetah 1"
B <- 2018
C <- c(0, 9.14, 18.29, 36.58)
D <- c(.2, 1.71, 2.71, 4.52)

Measured <- as.data.frame(cbind(A, B, C, D))
colnames(Measured) <- c('Animal', 'Year', 'Length', 'Height') 

H <- "Cheetah 2"
I <- 2018
J <- c(0, 9.14, 18.29, 36.58)
K <- c(.2, 1.78, 2.81, 4.61)

Measured2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(H, I, J, K))
colnames(Measured2) <- c('Animal', 'Year', 'Length', 'Height') 

Measured3 <- rbind(Measured, Measured2)
Measured3 <- split(Measured3, Measured3$Animal)

Measured3 <- lapply(Measured3, function(x){
x %>% 
   mutate(Length = as.numeric(as.character(Length)),
       Height = as.numeric(as.character(Height)))
 })

#initialize values
Var1 = 15
Var2 = 5

x0 = c(Var1,Var2)


#define function to optimise: optim will minimize the output
f <- function(x, a, b) {


y=0
#variables will be optimise to find the minimum value of f

V_1 = x[1]
V_2 = x[2]

 Predicted_X <- V_1 * (a - V_2 + V_2*exp(-a/V_2))

  y = sum((Predicted_X - b)^2)

    return(y)

 }

Y <- optim(x0, f, a = Measured3$`Cheetah 1`$Height,  b =  Measured3$`Cheetah 1`$Length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `for` loop for a quick fix:

```
nr_cheetahs <- length(Measured3)
optim_results <- vector("list", nr_cheetahs) 
for (i in seq(1, nr_cheetahs)){
 optim_results[[i]] <- optim(par=x0, fn=f, a=Measured3[[i]]['Height'], b=Measured3[[i]]['Length'])
}

# optim_results[[1]] provides the same result as your Y
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not accurate? Given your question, it's not clear how or if any of the other values in your dataframes (i.e. 'Animal' and 'Year') influence length and height, so I simply extracted those data pairs that are used in the optimization / f function. Please elaborate.

Comment: Ok, it seems you deleted your comment, i.e. is the issue solved?

Comment: The issue is not solved. When you run the code I provided, you get the results provided below, which are correct, with code you provided, they are not producing the same correct values:                                                                                        $par
[1] 10.465813  1.038046

$value
[1] 0.03611693

$counts
function gradient 
      97       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I thought the weight and length pairs are individuals. Please check my edit for a quick fix with a for loop.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: No worries, you're welcome, but please be aware that the common method to thank somebody for a helpful comment is to vote his comment up.